# Differences between npm link and npm install

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, npm

Internally, we have two javascript projects, a library project and an application project.  Historically, we've not built the library project but instead just used `npm link` to point to the directory where its installed.

I'm trying to see if I can instead publish that library to some central location (we have an internal npm repository), and then pull it in as a node module when building the actual app.  The publishing step works fine, I can get my module out there and then pull it in to my local node_modules.  However, when trying to build the app, I get an error like this:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Backbone.Model')
at     /var/folders/ls/0p_x0l3x6kd3cdft_nqg12b80000gp/T/2c192c0e2f7c8d30faaebd14a0439c4d.browserify:44361 <- ../node_modules/applib/base/SomeModel.js:18:0
```

We use commonjs for dependency management.  We're using Backbone, and I checked the file `SomeModel` has a require on backbone defined, but for some reason that doesn't work when I use the published module.  I did look at the underlying node module and backbone's looks much different than most of the other ones I've seen, but I'm not sure if that's an issue or not.  The declaration looks something like this

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var _ = require('underscore');
var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
```